# Alternative of isDisplayed() in Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

```
public void privateCohortCreation() {
    if(webElements.newCohortElm.isDisplayed()) {
        SeleniumUtils.click(getDriver(),webElements.createCohortSelectionFromMenu);
        webElements.cohortname.sendKeys("private_cohort_test");
        SeleniumUtils.click(getDriver(),webElements.createCohortButton);
    }
    else {
        doApply();
    }
}
```

I want that if the element is displayed then perform the task else call `doApply()` method. But this is giving an exception

```
"no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/app-root/div/app-container/app-indv301/app-global-filters/div/ul/li[3]/app-cohort/div/div/app-status/div"} (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)"
```

Comment: You get the exception another place, where you use `driver.findElement`. You are unable to locate the element.

Comment: Inside SeleniumUtils class check implementation for **click** method which creates wrapper around `findElement` or `findElements` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using try catch instead of if else.

```
 try {
            if (webElements.newCohortElm.isDisplayed()) {
                doApply();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            SeleniumUtils.click(getDriver(), webElements.createCohortSelectionFromMenu);
            webElements.cohortname.sendKeys("private_cohort_test");
            SeleniumUtils.click(getDriver(), webElements.createCohortButton);
        }
```

Comment: Yeah , I tried this and It worked for me. Thanks for Suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can use `findElements()` to check whether the element is on the webpage.

`findElements()` - returns empty list if there is no element with given locator
`findElement()` - throws `NoSuchElementException` if element is not on the page

Try below code:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.locator);
if(!elements.isEmpty()) {
    if(elements.get(0).isDisplayed()) {
       elements.get(0).click();
    }
    else {
       // element not visible 
    }

}else{
  // here mention code if element not present   
}
```

**Recommendation :** Use relative xpath instead of absolute xpath. or try CSS selector instead.

Comment: You've already scraped the page with the first `driver.findElements()` call... don't scrape the page two more times to check if it's displayed and click it. Store the collection from the first call in a variable and then use `.get(0)` to check if it's displayed and click it. See the update I made.